# Webpack Devserver HistoryApiFallback

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server, html5-history

I have my React webpack devserver set up like the following:

```
devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api': 'http://localhost:8080'
        }
    },
```

Now I also need to add `disabledDotRule: true` to the historyApiFallback.
Can someone help me to do that?
If I try just to change it to

```
historyApiFallback: {
            disableDotRule: true,
        },
```

I get the following ECONNREFUSED error:

`Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/.../ from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8080`

I guess the problem is that `historyApiFallback: true` is missing. How do I keep that while also adding `disabledDotRule: true`?

Comment: Is your react dev server running on 3000 or 8080?

Comment: The dev server is running on 3000 while my backend is on port 8080 on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, I misunderstood your question.

Could you try the following things and see if any work:

(1) Replace "http:localhost:8080" with "http://[::1]:8080" like so:

```js
proxy:{
  "/api":"http://[::1]:8080"
}
```

(2) Run the API on a different port like 8081 and see if you get the same error

Comment: What is the difference to my code snippet which is not working?